# How can I get request URLs in Swift webview

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiwebview, webkit, wkwebview

I'm currently working on an app that uses a webview to log in. I've done the exact same thing before on Flutter and was able to intercept and read the token from an incoming request URL. I need to do it in a different Swift application now but am stuck on how to proceed.

I've been trying to do the same thing in Swift to no luck with a couple methods using the navigation delegate but that only gave me the current URL and I cannot find a way to get request URLs from webview for the life of me.

This sign in has to be done in webview since it's done via a third party service and I need to get a token back before it redirects to the main page of the website.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and read [ask] for tips how to write a good question. You can [edit] your question with a [example] showing what you have already tried and what part is not working. This will help others answering your question.

Comment: I think, you need to explain how this sign-in scheme works. If it's a web bases sign-in, I fear it's not very well suited for native apps. From a security point of view, I suspect it's not very secure anyway. Perhaps, this third party server provides an API for native Apps, possibly some industry standard?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper it uses SAML to log in, and I can't really access the saml page without using a webview. It's made for a website rather than an app but use rest endpoints from that website that need a token. Since SAML uses a third party log in service like Google, I can't really use an api for it. I just need to intercept one of the request URLs it sends back in webview

Comment: SAML is an (older) open standard, so this is a good thing. In theory, any SAML identity provider should do it to authenticate a user and grant access to the resource service. There are third party libraries, which may help to realise an integration of SAML in the app. I would recommend to go this route. For example,  take a look at [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/identity-providers/enterprise-identity-providers/saml) which also provides a lot of useful help. These will use a SafariViewController as a web interface, and not WKWebView.

Comment: In order to provide and alternative, you may also look at this third party: https://docs.logto.io/tutorial/how-to-build-saml-sign-in-with-ios-swift-and-logto/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.